# How do I run nested collect on java 8 stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects A, A has a property called Address which has a street name -- streetName

From the list of objects A I want to getList of all the street names. One level collection seems quite doable from streams but how do I get nested String using one line of code.

So for getting list of addresses from object A I can do this:

```
listOfObjectsA.stream().map(a::getAddress).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My ultimate aim is to get list of street names, so I am not able to figure out a  second level collection using lambdas.

I couldnt find the precise example I was looking for. Could someone please help me with this.

Comment: Don't forget you can also use a single lambda expression: `.map(a -> a.getAddress().getStreetName())`

Comment: @AlexisC. Yes that works too along with the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply chain another `map` operation to get the street names:

```
listOfObjectsA
.stream()
.map(a::getAddress)
.map(a -> a.getStreetName())  // or a::getStreetName
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The first `map` transforms your objects into `Address` objects, the next `map` takes those `Address` objects and transforms them into `street names`, which are then collected by the collector.

The stream operations form a pipeline, so you can have as many operations as you need before the terminal operations (in this case, the `collect` operation).